# Flatten the Data in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, pivot

I have `dimensions.key_value`   of RECORD type i run the following query with following output.

```
SELECT *  from table;

   event_id   value     dimensions
     1        140      {"key_value": [{"key": "app", "value": "20"}]}
     2        150      {"key_value": [{"key": "region", "value": "8"}, {"key": "loc", "value": "1"}]}
     3        600      {"key_value": [{"key": "region", "value": "8"}, {"key": "loc", "value": "2"}]}
```

To unnest the data i have created the following view:

```
with temp as (
  select 
    (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'region') as region,
    (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'loc') as loc,
    (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'app') as app,
    value,
    event_id
    
  from table t
) select *
from temp;
```

My Output:

```
region   loc       app   count  event_id
null    null       20     140      1   
 8       1         null   150      2
 8       2         null.  600.     3
```

There are two thing i need to verify is my query correct ?
How i can make the query generic i.e if i don't know all the `key`, there some other keys may also be present in our dataset ?

Update:

My Schema :
[image]

My OutPut :
[image]

Problem : Let says a user want to do group by using `region` and `loc` so there is no easy way of writing the query for that i decided create a view so user can easily do group by

```
 with temp as (
      select 
        (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'region') as region,
        (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'loc') as loc,
        (select value from t.dimensions.key_value where key = 'store') as store,
        value,
        metric_name, event_time
        
      from table t
    ) select *
    from temp;
```

Based on this view the user can easily do group by. So i wanted to check if their is way to create generic view since we don't know the all the unique `key` or is there a easy way to do groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How i can make the query generic i.e if i don't know all the key, there some other keys may also be present in our dataset ?

Consider below

```
execute immediate (select
  ''' select event_id, value, ''' || string_agg('''
    (select value from b.key_value where key = "''' || key_name || '''") as ''' || key_name , ''', ''')
  || '''
  from (
    select event_id, value,
      array(
        select as struct 
          json_extract_scalar(kv, '$.key') key, 
          json_extract_scalar(kv, '$.value') value
        from a.kvs kv
      ) key_value
    from `project.dataset.table`,
    unnest([struct(json_extract_array(dimensions, '$.key_value') as kvs)]) a
  ) b
  '''
  from (
    select distinct json_extract_scalar(kv, '$.key') key_name
    from `project.dataset.table`,
    unnest(json_extract_array(dimensions, '$.key_value')) as kv
  )
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - ooutput is

[image]

As you can see in query - there is no any explicit references to actual key names  - rather they are dynamically extracted - so no need to know them in advance and there can be any number of them too

Comment: I am getting this error - `No matching signature for function JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY for argument types: STRUCT<key_value ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>>, STRING. Supported signature: JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(STRING, [STRING]) at [21:12]`

Comment: I have updated the question with the snapshot of the schema

Comment: In your original question - sample of data clearly looked as if dimensions field is of string data type representing json - so my answer is for that case. :o( But the solution is generic enough - you should be able to just adjust it to whatever schema you have . just apply a little extra efforts. Hope my answer still helpful for you. So try!

Comment: i tried to use `unnest(dimensions.key_value) as kv` but still facing some issue can you please explain the approach it will be very helpful

Comment: will get back to this tomorrow (if no-one else will help by that time)

Comment: will i am be able to create a view out of this so the users can directly query this view instead of original table

Comment: no you cannot create view that consists script

Comment: Is there a way to create a view out of this ?

Comment: if you have static (known in advance all keys) - yes, you can! but in your question you asked for generic solution for case when you don't know in advance all the keys - in this case you need to use scripting and thus no view on top of it is possible (Only SELECT statements are allowed in view queries)

Comment: In case if i know all the value is my query is correct which i have mentioned in the question

Comment: i realized  - presented sample as well as partial schema is not uniquely identifies your exact case, so I will hold on with further answers till more details provided :o(

Comment: I was wondering even with script can i update the view periodically so that i don't have to know all the `key` value ?

Comment: sure. you can use script to update view definition periodically

Comment: can you please explain the script you have wrote i try to change it but facing some issue: 
https://ideone.com/vtzyrW

Comment: i trying to understand the middle part

Comment: with above script i am trying to understand how to update an view...

Comment: i am able to solve the problem.. thanks for the script one thing if you can guide me how i can update my view with the above script ?

Comment: i tried using this `execute immediate (
  create view dataset.TEMP as`. but not working :(